# jquery with wcf not hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, wcf

Is it possible to have jquery talk to my wcf service that is hosted as a window service?
or it really needs to be hosted on IIS?

Also my regular wcf service don't have all this WebInvoke, AspNetCompatibilityRequirements. In it's current state can I use jquery to talk to my current wcf without making changes to it?

For example,

```
public interface IMyService
{ 
     [OperationContract]
     string SayHello();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
     public string SayHello(){ return "Hello"; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking you can, but it will be a little complex thing. It will technically amount to convert your windows service to a http listener. To do so :

1. Stop IIS server
2. Configure your Windows Service to use tcpBindings over Soap
3. The Windows Service should be bound to port 80 (HTTP)
4. Start the Windows Service. Make a normal call from browser to see how it works. It should allow exchanged of Xml over Soap.

You can also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392622/ajax-call-to-wcf-windows-service-over-ssl-https) where the user is able to implement a Windows Service over HTTP.